# ODE for the Cholesky decomposition of a SPD matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let $P$ be a spd matrix and consider the ODE
$$ \frac{dP}{dt} = FP + PF^\top + C.$$

The ODE makes sure that $P(t)$ is spd for any $t$.

I would prefer to obtain the Cholesky decomposition of $P = L L^\top$ instead. The ODE would then be

$$\frac{d (L L^\top)}{dt} = F L L^\top + L L^\top F^\top + C.$$

Is there any way I can rewrite this as an ODE for $L$ only, i.e,

$$\frac{dL}{dt} = g(t)?$$

If so, what is $g$? In particular, $P$ is large so I would prefer not to solve for $P$ and then do a Cholesky decomposition afterwards.

Comment: Can you give a reference about your first differential equation $\frac{dP}{dt} = FP + PF^\top + C.$ ? Indeed, it's hard to understand the following sentence with its "makes sure that"

Comment: Maybe connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3561750.

Comment: See section 6.2 in https://users.aalto.fi/~asolin/sde-book/sde-book.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !